# ASP.NET MVC Custom URL - Virtual Server Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I know how to setup a route to a url like http://siteurl.com/mycustomaccount/dashboard, but I would like to customize the "url" portion with a custom virtual server path such as http://mycustomaccount.siteurl.com/dashboard.

I want users signing up to have their account "mycustomaccount" setup so that I can intercept the request and provide the appropriate account information.  This is not very important to me or the users, but is a nice to have feature.

How do I setup my route map and can I setup the account without a physical folder on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this blog post about the same thing. The author (Maarten Balliauw) also provides the code in a zip file at the end of the article.

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx